# How to find the elapsed time between send and receive data?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using the System.Timers.Timer class. And I enable when I send a message and disable when I receive the message. How do I calculate how much time has elapsed. I have set the interval as 1 sec

Basically I retransmit data after 1000 sec again if I do not  recive an ACK. I retransmit 5 times max until I get a Ack. If I receive and something before 150ms then I stop retrnsmission.

Here's the code:

```
timer1.interval = 1000;
port.Write(data)
timer1.enabled = true;
```

event handler for the received data.

```
timer1.enabled=false;
```

Comment: Would http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx (System.Threading.Timer) be suitable?

Comment: @tommieb Yes. I think that System.Threading.Timer would be appropriate because I do need to keep track of elapsed time and also a count of how many times it got executed etc. Any other suggestions based on the information provided ...

Answer (score 7):

Use Stopwatch instead.

```
Stopwatch clock = Stopwatch.StartNew();
port.Write(data);
```

and in the handler

```
clock.Stop();
Console.WriteLine( clock.Elapsed );
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not what the System.Timers.Timer class is for. Take a look at System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch instead.

Answer (score 1):

The `Timer` class is not for measuring elapsed time - it's for generating an event on a regular, timed basis.

What you probably want is the [`Stopwatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) class (visit the link):

```
var sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
port.Write(data);
sw.Stop();
var elapased = sw.Elapsed;  // elapsed is a TimeSpan
```

The `Elapsed` property is a [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) which has methods and properties for evaluating the amount of time passed in different ways.

Comment: After the elapsed time of 1 sec I need to retransmit the data. And I can do this for a maximum of 5 times. This is to do with the ACK/Nak and data exchange between 2 dvices. So there is an event that needs to be fired.

Comment: I wouldn't use a timer for this kind of communication exchange. Timers are more appropriate for processing that is not time sensitive. The event is not gauranteed to be fired at the interval you may expect - and if you are inside the event handler you may "lose" some of the events. For things like network or inter-device I/O you probably want to use either a single-threaded loop with some wait logic (or sempahores) or something more like completion ports (which are more complicated).

Comment: You may want to consider rephrasing the question and adding more information about what you're doing - if you want an answer. I'm not the only responder that thought you were trying to measure elapsed time.